# IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder() equivalent in WinRT?

Tags: c#, network-programming, windows-8, windows-runtime, endianness

The IPAddress class doesn't seem to exist in the WinRT API. Is there an equivalent to `IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder()` available for converting an int from Host order to Network order (Little Endian to Big Endian)?

Comment: There might not be a method.  You can always write one yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing my own method. It's really simple. All it does is reverse the byte order. Here it is for your copy-and-pasting pleasure:

```
public static int ReverseEndianness(int num)
{
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(num);
    byte[] reversedBytes = new byte[bytes.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        reversedBytes[i] = bytes[bytes.Length - 1 - i];
    }

    return BitConverter.ToInt32(reversedBytes, 0);
}
```

Comment: One can use [Array.Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/d3877932(v=vs.110).aspx) to reverse the array.

Answer (score 3):

In many cases (not all of course) you can use **DataReader** and **DataWriter** for that:

```
DataReader reader = new DataReader(stream.AsInputStream());
reader.ByteOrder = ByteOrder.BigEndian;  // standard network byte order
reader.ReadInt16();
```

For compatibility reasons I used reflector:

```
    public static short HostToNetworkOrder(short host)
    {
        return (short)(((host & 0xff) << 8) | ((host >> 8) & 0xff));
    }

    public static int HostToNetworkOrder(int host)
    {
        return (((HostToNetworkOrder((short)host) & 0xffff) << 0x10) | (HostToNetworkOrder((short)(host >> 0x10)) & 0xffff));
    }

    public static long HostToNetworkOrder(long host)
    {
        return (long)(((HostToNetworkOrder((int)host) & 0xffffffffL) << 0x20) | (HostToNetworkOrder((int)(host >> 0x20)) & 0xffffffffL));
    }

    public static short NetworkToHostOrder(short network)
    {
        return HostToNetworkOrder(network);
    }

    public static int NetworkToHostOrder(int network)
    {
        return HostToNetworkOrder(network);
    }

    public static long NetworkToHostOrder(long network)
    {
        return HostToNetworkOrder(network);
    }
```